# Facebook Graph API Post to wall

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use this method to post a photo to a Facebook wall.

```
/// <param name="method">Http Method</param>
/// <param name="url">Full url to the web resource</param>
/// <param name="postData">Data to post in querystring format</param>
/// <returns>The web server response.</returns>

public string WebRequest(Method method, string url, string postData)
{
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = null;
    StreamWriter requestWriter = null;
    string responseData = "";
    webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    webRequest.Method = method.ToString();
    webRequest.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
    webRequest.UserAgent = "[]";
    webRequest.Timeout = 20000;

    if (method == Method.POST)
    {
        webRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        requestWriter = new StreamWriter(webRequest.GetRequestStream());
        try
        {
            requestWriter.Write(postData);
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            requestWriter.Close();
            requestWriter = null;
        }
    }
    responseData = WebResponseGet(webRequest);
    webRequest = null;
    return responseData;
}
```

What I'm having problem with is the postData. I can't get it to work, and I'm not sure what that string would look like? Can anyone give an example?

Comment: Is there an error? What you mean by "I can't get it to work?"

Comment: Nothing is getting posted. It posted a message to the wall one time, but that's it.

Comment: do you have valid token? could it be that it expired?

Answer (score 0):

You need to post to https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN,
and the posted data should look like

> message=This is a test message

(you should escape special characters within the message with [Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx), but don't escape the '=')

You can also specify other properties (as defined in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed#publish)), for example:

> message={escaped message here}&link={urlencoded link here}&caption={escaped caption text here}&title={escaped title text here}&description={escaped description text here}&picture={urlencoded picture url}

(Without the curly braces of course.) This will embed a link into your post, that has a title, a caption, a description, and a thumbnail image of your choice.

We can't see your `WebResponseGet` method, but you should check what the responseData contains when the posting doesn't succeed. Alternatively, look for HTTP status codes and WebExceptions within your WebResponseGet. It helps to read the returned data; facebook returns errors in a JSON format like this (example):

> {"error":{"message":"Missing message or
>   attachment.","type":"FacebookApiException","code":100,"error_subcode":1349125}}

Be aware that posting requires the `publish_actions` permission for your application (you need to add it to the scope when requesting the access token, if it wasn't in the scope when you requested the token, you need a new token).